# How does stack size of pthread affects memory usage?

Tags: c, pthreads, libc

I have a question about setting the stack size of pthread using `pthread_attr_setstacksize()`:

From my understanding, the stack of pthread lies on the anonymous mmapped region of its creating process. When I set the thread's stack size to 5M & 8M separately, I see that it does affect the size of the mmapped region but both of them use (almost) the same amount of physical memory:

Partial result of the pmap command [stack with size 5M]:

> 00007f97f8b52000   7172K rw---   [ anon ]

Partial result of the pmap command [stack with size 8M]:

> 00007f8784606000  10244K rw---   [ anon ]

Partial result of the top command [stack with size 5M]:

> VIRT    RES   SWAP   USED

```
 25160   7236      0   7236
```

Partial result of the top command [stack with size 8M]:

> VIRT    RES   SWAP   USED

```
 22088   7196      0   7196
```

In my program, I want to use a larger stack size to prevent a stack overflow; what I want to confirm here is that by using a large stack size, I will not consume more physical memory but just larger virtual address. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a larger stack size to prevent overflow, that implies at some point you'll actually be *using* the larger size (ie, your stack will be deeper than the default would allow).

In that case, there's some point where your program would have crashed with the default stack size, where it instead has another page allocated to its address space. So, in some sense, it *could* use more physical memory.

How many of the pages allocated to your process actually reside in memory at one time, however, depends your OS, memory pressure, other processes etc. etc.